# Trouble with SqlExpression<T>.Join() and column names

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

I ran into an issue where I have used ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows to build a join query between a table and a view, and the sql emitted contains a select statement with columns like this:

```
SELECT "Country"."Id", "Country"."Code", "Country"."Title", ...
```

As far as I can tell, this is perfectly valid SQL, but when I call `IDbConnection.Select<Country>(expr)`, Ormlite doesn't map the fields correctly to the POCO.  (I get the right number of results, but all of the fields in each object are null)

Here's the code I'm working with, unfortunately I couldn't get a reduced example to display the same issue:

**Repository.cs**

```
public List<Country> FilterValidCountries(ProgrammingMapFilter filter) {
    using (_db.BeginTransaction()) {
        var q = _db.From<Country>()
            .Join<Mid, ProgrammingMapView>((mid, map) => mid.Id == map.Mid)
            .Join<Country, Mid>((country, mid) => country.Code == mid.CountryCode)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Title);

        if (filter.ProductId.HasValue)
            q = q.Where<ProgrammingMapView>(x => x.ProductId == filter.ProductId);

        if (filter.ProtocolId.HasValue)
            q = q.Where<ProgrammingMapView>(x => x.ProtocolId == filter.ProtocolId);

        return _db.Select(q);
    }
}
```

**Models**

```
public class Country {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ShortTitle { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Mid {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class ProgrammingMapView {
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProtocolId { get; set; }
    public int Mid { get; set; }
}
```

**Schema**

```
create table Country (
    Id integer primary key,
    Code text,
    Title text,
    ShortTitle text,
    ModifiedOn text,
    ModifiedBy integer
);

create table Mid (
    Id integer primary key,
    CountryCode text,
    ModifiedOn text,
    ModifiedBy integer
);

create view ProgrammingMapView as
  select
    p.Id ProductId
  , pt.Id ProtocolId
  , m.Id Mid
  from Mid m
    join MidProduct mprod on (mprod.RegisteredMid = m.Id)
    join Product p on (p.Id = mprod.ProductId)
    join MidProtocol mprot on (mprot.RegisteredMid = m.Id)
    join ProtocolType pt on (pt.Id = mprot.ProtocolId)
    join ProductProtocol pp on (pp.ProductId = p.Id and pp.ProtocolTypeId = pt.Id)
;
```

**Sql emitted**

```
SELECT "Country"."Id", "Country"."Code", "Country"."Title", "Country"."ShortTitle",    "Country"."ModifiedOn", "Country"."ModifiedBy" 
FROM "Country" 
INNER JOIN "ProgrammingMapView"  ON ("Mid"."Id" = "ProgrammingMapView"."Mid") 
INNER JOIN "Mid"  ON ("Country"."Code" = "Mid"."CountryCode")
WHERE ("ProgrammingMapView"."ProductId" = 87)
ORDER BY "Country"."Title" ASC
```

## Debugging

I tracked the issue down to ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteExtensions.cs:323 (v4.0.30).  In `TryGuessColumnIndex()`, when Ormlite calls `dataReader.GetName(i)`, the GetName method always returns "Country".  (Not "Country.Id" or "Country.Title")

```
private static int TryGuessColumnIndex(string fieldName, IDataReader dataReader)
{
    if (OrmLiteConfig.DisableColumnGuessFallback)
        return NotFound;

    var fieldCount = dataReader.FieldCount;
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
    {
        var dbFieldName = dataReader.GetName(i);
        ....
```

That leads me to believe that the System.Data.Sqlite.Core library that I have installed doesn't parse quoted, table qualified identifiers like that correctly.  System.Data.Sqlite.Core (v1.0.93) displays the same behavior without using servicestack.ormlite:

```
using (var cn = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", dbPath2)))
{
    cn.Open();

    var query = @"
        SELECT ""Country"".""Id"", ""Country"".""Code"", ""Country"".""Title"", ""Country"".""ShortTitle"", ""Country"".""ModifiedOn"", ""Country"".""ModifiedBy"" 
        FROM ""Country"" INNER JOIN ""ProgrammingMapView""  ON (""Mid"".""Id"" = ""ProgrammingMapView"".""Mid"") INNER JOIN ""Mid""  ON (""Country"".""Code"" = ""Mid"".""CountryCode"")
        WHERE (""ProgrammingMapView"".""ProductId"" = 87)
        ORDER BY ""Country"".""Title"" ASC
        ";

    using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, cn))
    {
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(reader.GetName(i) + ", ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Country, Country, Country, Country, Country, Country,
Country, Country, Country, Country, Country, Country,
```

## What do I do?

Is there something I've missed in the configuration of ServiceStack.Ormlite or System.Data.Sqlite that will allow `IDataReader.GetName(i)` to return the correct column name (and not just the Table name)?